# Hazelcast web clustered session service: Retrying the connection

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

hazelcast unable to connect, the message receive is as follows

```
2018-03-03 10:27:51,074 INFO c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6] Picked Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5703], bind any local is true
2018-03-03 10:28:01.078  INFO 19478 --- [.ensureInstance] c.hazelcast.web.ClusteredSessionService  : Retrying the connection!!
2018-03-03 10:28:01,078 INFO c.h.w.ClusteredSessionService Retrying the connection!!
2018-03-03 10:28:01.079  INFO 19478 --- [.ensureInstance] com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator    : Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
2018-03-03 10:28:01,079 INFO c.h.c.XmlConfigLocator Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
2018-03-03 10:28:01.085  INFO 19478 --- [.ensureInstance] c.hazelcast.web.HazelcastInstanceLoader  : Creating a new HazelcastInstance for session replication
2018-03-03 10:28:01,085 INFO c.h.w.HazelcastInstanceLoader Creating a new HazelcastInstance for session replication
2018-03-03 10:28:01.086  INFO 19478 --- [.ensureInstance] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6] Picked Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5703], bind any local is true
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue here?

Comment: Looks like Hazecast is starting up with the default configs (`hazelcast-default.xml`), meaning it can't pick up your configuration, if any. Can you also provide your configs and describe what you want to achieve?